# Why does IE10 see response but not IE9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC app, when I hit a specific URL, The ActionResult method sends back a 204 response.  In IE10, I see this in the Developer Tools Network tab and also in Fiddler.  But in IE9, I don't see it in either the network tab or Fiddler.

Is there something about IE9 that would cause this?

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache

Comment: 204 is no content, it could be that IE 9 is just ignoring it. What does your action result contain ( besides setting status?)

Comment: There is some processing of received data (send to database) in the action method.  The last line in that method is return 204.  I did clear IE temp files but no change.

Answer (score 0):

If fiddler is not picking up the request, then it sounds like the request is being cached.

Is this an AJAX request?

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Or in the actual AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
     data: foo,
     url: bar,
     cache: false
});
```